# Is "getNumPartitions" an expensive operation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `pyspark`, and I call `getNumPartitions()` to see if I need to `repartition` and it is dramatically slowng down my code.  The code is too large to post here.  My code works like this:

- I have a `for` loop that loops through a bunch of functions that will be applied to a `DataFrame`
- Obviously these are applied lazily, so they don't get applied until the end of the for loop.
- Many of them are `withColumn` functions, or `pivot` functions like this: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html
- At each iteration, I print out the number of partitions by `getNumPartitions()`

I was under the impression that this is not an expensive operation...am I mis understanding and is it actually expensive?  Or is something else slowing down my code?

Comment: Are you sure it's the call to `getNumPartitions()` that's slowing it down? Or is it maybe that you're now repartitioning differently?

Comment: I'm only calling `getNumPartitions()`.  I'm not repartitioning at all...

Comment: AFAIK it's no that expensive, at least it's not "firing" a spark-job. But it can easily take 10-20s in my experience.

Comment: And does it depend on how large the RDD/DataFrame is?  Perhaps that is the issue....?

Comment: Repartitioning can be expensive or virtually free depending on the context, and the context is what is missing here. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for `getNumPartitions()`...

```
def getNumPartitions(self): 
    return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
```

it should not be that expensive. I suspect that there is something else going on that's causing your slow down.

Here's what I do know:

- The list of partitions are cached and so only the first call to `partitions()` will cause the partitions to be calculated
- Spark has to calculate the partitions for each RDD anyway, so it shouldn't add any more time for you to query the count